# How to add Buttons in WinForm in Runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following Code :

```
public GUIWevbDav()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //My XML Loading and other Code Here

        //Trying to add Buttons here
        if (DisplayNameNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DisplayNameNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                Button folderButton = new Button();
                folderButton.Width = 150;
                folderButton.Height = 70;
                folderButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                folderButton.Text = DisplayNameNodes[i].InnerText;

                Now trying to do  GUIWevbDav.Controls.Add
                (unable to get GUIWevbDav.Controls method )

            }
        }
```

I dont want to create a form at run time but add the dynamically created buttons to my Current Winform i.e: GUIWevDav

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem in your code is that you're trying to call `Controls.Add()` method on `GUIWevbDav` which is the type of your form and you can't get Control.Add on a type, it's not a static method. It only works on instances.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DisplayNameNodes.Count; i++) 
{ 

    Button folderButton = new Button(); 
    folderButton.Width = 150; 
    folderButton.Height = 70; 
    folderButton.ForeColor = Color.Black; 
    folderButton.Text = DisplayNameNodes[i].InnerText; 

    //This will work and add button to your Form.
    this.Controls.Add(folderButton );

    //you can't get Control.Add on a type, it's not a static method. It only works on instances.
    //GUIWevbDav.Controls.Add

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use `this.Controls.Add(folderButton)`. `this` is your form.

Comment: Thanks Petar, But m curiosu to know why can't we we use the name of the form as 'this' and 'GUIWevbDav' refer to the same form.

Comment: "this" is a keyword for accessing the current object. If you use directly "GUIWevbDav" then you are not working with instances of "GUIWevbDav" anymore and you access its static members. But "Controls" is not a static member. And you get an error of course. Read more about static here in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to work with [`Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property.
In [`Form Class Members`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_members.aspx) you can see `Controls` property.

Use it like this :

```
this.Controls.Add(folderButton);  // "this" is your form class object.
```